# Fragement no longer exists for key Error

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have an application with three tabs (TabWidget using fragments). Each tab opens a fragment that contains a a view pager that is based on FragmentStatePagerAdapter. The view pager is populated with items fetched from an online server using Async task.

My problem:

- I click on tab 1, then it begins loading the items(using asyncTask)
- Then I click tab 2, which agains starts loading.
- When I click again on tab 1, the application force closes withe the stack trace shown below:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(29658): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(29658): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragement no longer exists for key f1: index 1
E/AndroidRuntime(29658):        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.getFragment(FragmentManager.java:564)
E/AndroidRuntime(29658):        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.restoreState(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:211)
E/AndroidRuntime(29658):        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onRestoreInstanceState(ViewPager.java:1220)
E/AndroidRuntime(29658):        at android.view.View.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(View.java:11910)
E/AndroidRuntime(29658):        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2584)
E/AndroidRuntime(29658):        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2590)
E/AndroidRuntime(29658):        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2590)
E/AndroidRuntime(29658):        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2590)
E/AndroidRuntime(29658):        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2590)
E/AndroidRuntime(29658):        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2590)
E/AndroidRuntime(29658):        at android.view.View.restoreHierarchyState(View.java:11888)
E/AndroidRuntime(29658):        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.restoreViewState(Fragment.java:417)
E/AndroidRuntime(29658):        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:933)
E/AndroidRuntime(29658):        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.attachFragment(FragmentManager.java:1264)
E/AndroidRuntime(29658):        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:672)
E/AndroidRuntime(29658):        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1444)
E/AndroidRuntime(29658):        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:429)
E/AndroidRuntime(29658):        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
E/AndroidRuntime(29658):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
E/AndroidRuntime(29658):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(29658):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
E/AndroidRuntime(29658):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(29658):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(29658):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
E/AndroidRuntime(29658):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
E/AndroidRuntime(29658):        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
W/ActivityManager(17922):   Force finishing activity com.abello.news/.MainActivity
```

Comment: We need code - otherwise we cannot know what you are doing and what causes the problem!

Comment: Category category1Adapter = new Category1Adapter(getChildFragmentManager(),category1Events.size());
ViewPager category1Pager = (ViewPager) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.image_slider_category1);               

category1Pager.setAdapter(category1Adapter);   where Category1Adapter is a class that extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter and category1Events is an arraylist. The line that is causing the error is this one:category1Pager.setAdapter(category1Adapter);@WolframRittmeyer hope this helps. Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry, but no, that's not enough. Please edit your question and add as much code as possible. Of your activity, your fragments, your adapters, of the tab handling code and maybe even parts of your XML layout definitions if they help to understand your construct.

Comment: @WolframRittmeyer seems like the OP has signed a very strict NDA with his project manager :D

Answer (score 3):

I know it's been taken much time, but there's no right answer.

Try to use `FragmentPagerAdapter` instead of `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`. Because the latter uses to save the state and doesn't update some data.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is this line:

```
Category category1Adapter = new Category1Adapter(getChildFragmentManager(),category1Events.size());
```

Instead of using `getChildFragmentManager()` you have to use `getFragmentManager()` in order to ensure that the Fragment is still around when the screen is recreated.

Comment: Fragment contain a view pager so how you can use getFragmentManager() instead of getChildFragmentManager()

Comment: retrieving its activity